# Can anyone explain to me how do default argument values work in recursive functions in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int factorial ( int n, int a = 1 ) {
 if ( n == 0 ) return a;
 return factorial ( n-1, a * n );
}
```

This is a recursive function that calculates factorial of n. I know and fully understand recursive functions, but I do not understand how do these recursive functions with default arguments such as "int a=1" work. For example, if I pass this:

```
factorial(3);
```

Can anyone write step by step what is going to happen? I can't understand what is happening with this argument "a" in every call of the function, if it changes or stays the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you think they work in *normal* functions? If you want a "step by step" just compile this and drop it into a debugger, stepping through the code line by line.

Comment: It's not a good look to say "I know and fully understand recursive functions" and then go to demonstrate that you don't. Be humble, admit what you don't know. We're all learning here.

Comment: they are used by the compiler when you do not provide your own argument.

Comment: So what happens if you *do* provide an argument? Why would a recursive call be treated differently?

Comment: then that argument is used instead of the default one.

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to learn about debugging, and that's really an essential skill. Visual Studio Code, Xcode and others all have built-in debuggers that you can engage, effectively, with a click of the mouse. It takes about 20-30 minutes to learn the basics. If you don't have either of those tools, there are other options (Eclipse? gdb?) but it depends on what you're using.

Comment: I think you've figured it out then.

Comment: You could even `cout << n << a` in the function. That will tell you a lot,

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I will try it out myself, I thought these default arguments work differently in recursive functions for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
factorial(3) -> "here a is implicitly considered as 1"
factorial(2, 1 * 3) -> 
factorial(1, 3 * 2) -> 
factorial(0, 6 * 1)-> 
return(6) "this is a case where n ==0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Default values only apply when the function call is not providing the values. The outer, initial call will use the default value for the 2nd argument, but the recursive calls won’t, since both argument values are provided in the call.

For the future, I do suggest you get used to running such code on eg. https://www.onlinegdb.com/, if you have trouble running the debugger locally on your machine.

TL;DR: default values only apply when the call is done with those arguments absent. They act as if they weren’t even there otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I do encourage you to practice with your debugger.

But in addition, it is often easy enough (and a different kind of valuable practice), to 'instrument-your-code' to directly illustrate (during its operation) 'how the default argument works in recursion'.

Consider this simple diagnostic-addition which uses a std::stringstream to delay the informative output until after the function completes:

```
stringstream m_ss; // diagnostic-addition

int factorial ( int n, int a = 1 )
{
  if ( n == 0 ) return a;

  if(true)  // diagnostic-addition 
  {  
    m_ss << "\n  " << setw(6-n) << ' ' << n << "  " << a;
    // indent showing-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- recursion-depth
  }

  return factorial ( n-1, a * n );
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
   cout << "\n  factorial(5) = " << factorial(5) << endl 
        << m_ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Then review the output:

```
   factorial(5) = 120
    
   5  1
    4  5
     3  20
      2  60
       1  120
```

This output show the recursion.

'decursion'

Some developers have difficulty envisioning the 'de-cursion'.  This too can be illustrated:

Replace the the last line of factorial(...) with:

```
int factorial ( int n, int a = 1 )
{
  if ( n == 0 ) return a;

  if(true)  // diagnostic-addition 
  {  
    m_ss << "\n  " << setw(6-n) << ' ' << n << "  " << a;
    // indent showing-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- recursion-depth
  }

  // return    factorial ( n-1, a * n );  // replace with

  int retVal = factorial ( n-1, a * n ); 

  if(true) // diagnostic-addition 
  {
    m_ss << "\n  " << setw(6-n) << ' ' << 'd' << n;
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

Review the output with the decursion marked:

```
  factorial(5) = 120

   5  1
    4  5
     3  20
      2  60
       1  120
       d1
      d2
     d3
    d4
   d5
```